# How can I find one unsorted element in otherwise sorted array? (In C)

Tags: arrays, c, sorting

These are the 3 test cases where they are sorted except for one out of place element:

{-17, -5, -5, -2, 1, 17, 289, 17, 17, 395} | Out of place element index is 6.

{289, 17, 17, 17, 100, 250, 300, 1000, 5000} | Out of place element index is 0.

{-1, 23, 70, 500, 1000, 7000, 23520, 10} | Out of place element index is 7.

This is the code I have so far:

```
int outlier;
int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int)
for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
  if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1])
    outlier = i;
}
```

For the first test case the outlier is 6 which is correct. For the second test case the outlier is 0 which is also correct. However when I try it on the third array I get the outlier as 6 which is not the position of the element in the incorrect position. It should equal 7. The goal is to write a function to: a) Find the index of the element where it is unsorted and b) Sort the array.

Comment: How do you expect your algorithm to return `size-1` (which is your 7) if it is never reaching it?

Comment: Sorry typo.. it is meant to be 70. I just edited it to reflect the correction.

Comment: Just changed it thank you, but the variable outlier is still being assigned the value of 6 not 7. @EugeneSh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Element *x* is not considered to be an outlier if the following is true:

```
previous <= x <= next
```

Sometimes an element has no *previous* or *next* (elements at both edges of an array). In that case, one can always *cook up* limits `MIN` and `MAX`, between which all array elements fall.

Something like this should work:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX (int) 1e6
#define MIN (int) -1e6

int main() {
    int arr[] = {-1, 23, 70, 500, 1000, 7000, 23520, 10};
    int size = 8;
    int outlier;
    int prev, x, next;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (i == 0) prev = MIN;
        else prev = arr[i - 1];

        if (i == size - 1) next = MAX;
        else next = arr[i + 1];

        x = arr[i];

        if (!(prev <= x && x <= next) && prev <= next) {
            outlier = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n", outlier); // outputs 7
}
```